# How create a spring batch to download files from api and insert data to database?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have create a spring batch project to be able to download CSV files from an API and insert the data from those csv files to postreSQL database. The download has been done, but the insert didn't work when i started the project from the first time. I have two jobs, one for the download, and the other for the insert. And for each job has a step. Please, is there someone can help me ? 
Thanks.

```
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Value("${filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Value("classpath:insertions_*.csv")
    private Resource[] inputResources;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, DataSource dataSource, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<SharadarFundamentalsDto> readerInsert() {
        FlatFileItemReader<SharadarFundamentalsDto> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);

        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<SharadarFundamentalsDto>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames("ticker","dimension","calendardate","datekey","reportperiod");
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {{
                setTargetType(SharadarFundamentalsDto.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<SharadarFundamentalsDto> multiResourceItemReader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<SharadarFundamentalsDto> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(readerInsert());
        return resourceItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public SharadarFundamentalsProcessor processor() {
        return new SharadarFundamentalsProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<SharadarFundamentals> writerInsert() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<SharadarFundamentals> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO public.sharadar_fundamentals(ticker, dimension, calendardate, datekey, reportperiod)" +
                "VALUES (:ticker, :dimension, :calendardate, :datekey, :reportperiod)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job downloadFiles(JobListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("downloadFiles")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job insertJob(JobListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("insertJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step2())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DownloadTasklet downloadTasklet() {
        return new DownloadTasklet();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(downloadTasklet())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<SharadarFundamentalsDto, SharadarFundamentals> chunk(10)
                .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(1)
                .skip(FlatFileParseException.class)
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writerInsert())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of two jobs, I would create a single job with two steps . The first step would be a tasklet that downlods the file and the second step would be a chunk oriented step to load data from the file to the db (a third, optional step, would remove the file if necessary).

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, I did as you said, but always for the first execution of the project, step 1 worked well (download files) and for step 2, it does not see the CSV files so the number of insertions equal to 0.

Comment: The reader of step 2 should be step scoped and point to the file downloaded in step 1. Please refer to the [late binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a single job that performs 2 tasks synchronously.

```
    @Bean
    public Job downloadFilesAndInsertData(JobListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("downloadFiles")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: I did as you said, but always for the first execution of the project, step 1 worked well (download files) and for step 2, it does not see the files so the number of insertions equal to 0.

Comment: No worries, what I posted was not meant to be the complete solution, but merely show that it is 1 job with 2 steps. I will look into the rest of it a bit later tonight and get you unstuck.